# VB.Net load JS file if file exists

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to do this on a DotNetNuke site with multiple portals, so I want to do this server-side VB loads a javascript file if it exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% 'If the portal.js exists, insert %>
<% if System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(PortalSettings.HomeDirectory & "portal.js")) then %>
<script src="<%= PortalSettings.HomeDirectory %>portal.js"></script>
<% end if %>
```